# transfer variable between frames

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

The questions similar to that I found a lot but still can not realize what I need. I have a page.php that loaded in the block din_content with function .load
Page.php

```
<div id="ess">
<div id="top_ch">
    <h1>Ess</h1>
</div>
    <div id="ch">
    <iframe name="users" width="220" height="510" align="left" src='ess/users.php' id="userch"></iframe>
    <iframe name="text"  width="450" height="405" src='ess/text.php'></iframe>
</div>
```

In page I have two Iframes. So I have two problems. First in main page where that iframes loaded I have Jquery function

```
    $(document).on('click','.link_pro',function () {  
//some actions
 });
```

How to make that that function also worked in iframe?

Second, In the first Iframe I have two links. So what I need is that depend of what link you click on, the variable 'active' changed and depend on the value of that variable changed the second iframe. In example, you click on the first link and variable 'active' =1  than it transfered to the second iframe (may be even transfer to the parent and try to send to the second iframe trough method Get) where depend of the value displayed a requested result. I try to realize it with jquery and php. But still didn't get the result. The most problem to get a result from clicking on links in the first Iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the iframes sources and they belong to the same domain as the top window, then, for attaching events, you could probably do something like:

```
jQuery("iframe").load(function(){
  jQuery(this).contents().find(".link_pro").on("click", function(){

  });
});
```

The code above will attach the click event to your iframe's content (.link_pro).

Then, for the second question, if you have, for example, in your top window:

```
var myTopVar; //This belongs to top window scope
```

From your iframe, you can access:

```
top.myTopVar;
```

I think that should be it but, again, both your top window and iframe should share the same domain (document.domain). If not, you will face [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problems.

Comment: thanks, I will try to realize it right now. All frames in the same domain, as you can see them in my question where I get a directory...